# How to alert error got from express backend using AJAX (jquery) in the frontend

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mongodb, express

The success function works perfectly fine when it comes to receiving data from the express backend server and manipulating it. I'm unable to handle error thrown by the backend properly. It is possible to get status code (400 or other) and the related text (Bad request, etc) but not the actual message which the express backend sends.

Backend login code

```
router.post("/users/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findByCredentails(
      req.body.email,
      req.body.password
    );
    const token = await user.generateAuthToken();
    res.send({ user, token });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ error: error.message }); //error.message is thrown by the database (which logs perfectly fine in the backend when some error occurs)
  }
});
```

Database code that sends the message (There is no error in this; putting this here just for the reference)

```
userSchema.statics.findByCredentails = async (email, password) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({ email });
  if (!user) throw new Error("Unable to find a user with the entered email");

  const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
  if (!isMatch) throw new Error("Incorrect password, try again");

  return user;
};
```

Frontend code (which is working fine for success but not error)

```
function login() {
        const data = {
          email: $("#email-field").val(),
          password: $("#password-field").val()
        };
        $.ajax({
          url: "/users/login",
          method: "POST",
          data,
          success: function(userData) {
            console.log(userData); //works just fine
          },
          error: function(jqXHR) {
            //how can I get that error message here. I'm able to get jqXHR.status and .textStatus but not the actual message that I want.
          }
        });
      }
```

Comment: Try `console.dir(jqXHR)` in the error handler. Then you should be able to find exactly where the error message you want to find is stored - assuming the backend makes it available to the client

Comment: console.dir(jqXHR) logged "object" with a dropdown which is empty.

Comment: Have you checked the other two arguments provided to the error callback?

Comment: Check console.log(jqXHR.responseJSON) or     console.log(jqXHR.responseText)

Comment: console.log(jqXHR.responseText) actually worked! Thanks a lot.